# Column header for LoadingRow WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I possibly put Header for my Loading Row. My datagrid looks like this:

[image]

I want to put a header above 1st Check, 2nd Check etc.

The first column is being created using Datagrid_LoadingRow. Here is the code:

```
void datagrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (counter.CheckCount > 1)
    {
        if ((e.Row.GetIndex() + 1) == 1)
            CheckNumber = "1st";
        else if ((e.Row.GetIndex() + 1) == 2)
            CheckNumber = "2nd";
        else if ((e.Row.GetIndex() + 1) == 3)
            CheckNumber = "3rd";
        else
            CheckNumber = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString() + "th";
        e.Row.Header = CheckNumber + " Check";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString()  + " Check";
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML for datagrid. May columns are in code using ItemSource.

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid" LoadingRow="datagrid_LoadingRow"  SelectionMode="Single" Margin="12,140,32,0" Height="310" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="746"
            BorderBrush="#FF444444" BorderThickness="1"  RowHeight="30" IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="12" ColumnWidth="*"  FontFamily="Arial"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutoGeneratingColumn="dgCheckSummary_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to make the header for the column where my row index is will be the same as the header for column Type, Amount, Edit and delete. Can anyone help me out? I'm using c# wpf. Thank you so much.

If possible can anyone tell me how can I put the row index in a column specifically in column 1? Thank so much.

Comment: probably you should do it in XAML not in code behind. Code that you posted is about loading rows not header. Can you paste XAML code as well?

Comment: That is called the RowHeader.  It does not have a ColumnHeader.  Maybe you could force one.  But why not just add a column at the first position?

Comment: @Blam, How can I possibly put the row index in a column without using LoadingRow? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Same way you put data in Type and Amount.

Comment: @Blam data of Type and Amount are from database.

Comment: You have a datasource.  You have the power to modify that datasource.

Answer (score 0):

here a full example  showing how you  can achieve a similar behavior without using the `Loading Row` event

**XAML**

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
            Title="MainWindow"
            Width="525"
            Height="350">
        <Window.Resources>
            <local:ConvertItemToIndex x:Key="IndexConverter"/>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="True">

                <!--Bind the Content property of the RowHeaderStyle to the Converter to create numbered rows-->
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            </DataGrid>


        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyData> Datas = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Datas.Add(new MyData() { Prop1 = "test prop" + i, Prop2 = "test prop" + i, });

            }
            this.DataContext = Datas;  
        }
    }
    public class MyData
    {

        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }


    }
    public class ConvertItemToIndex : IValueConverter
    {
        private static int checkNumber; 
        #region IValueConverter Members
        //Convert the Item to an Index
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {                
                return  "Check " + ++checkNumber; 

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(e.Message);
            }
        }
        //One way binding, so ConvertBack is not implemented
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }

}

**Result**
```

[image]